# Alicloud CMS alarm not showing data

Tags: terraform, alibaba-cloud

I have created alibaba cms alarm using terraform but it does not show any data. Below is my code.

```
resource "alicloud_cms_alarm" "scaleOut-alarm" {
    contact_groups     = ["example"]
    dimensions = {
      region = "shanghai"
      queue  = "queue"
  }
    enabled            = true
    metric             = "ActiveMessages"
    name               = "alarm-name"
    period             = 300
    project            = "acs_mns_new"
    silence_time       = 300
    operator           = ">"
    threshold          = 300
    statistics         = "Average"
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is basic example

```
    resource "alicloud_cms_alarm" "basic" {
  name    = "tf-testAccCmsAlarm_basic"
  project = "acs_ecs_dashboard"
  metric  = "disk_writebytes"
  dimensions = {
    instanceId = "i-bp1247,i-bp11gd"
    device     = "/dev/vda1,/dev/vdb1"
  }
  statistics      = "Average"
  period          = 900
  operator        = "<="
  threshold       = 35
  triggered_count = 2
  contact_groups  = ["test-group"]
  effective_interval = "0:00-2:00"
  notify_type     = 1
  webhook         = "https://${data.alicloud_account.current.id}.eu-central-1.fc.aliyuncs.com/2016-08-15/proxy/Terraform/AlarmEndpointMock/"
}
```

Comment: This is for ecs but I need the dimensions for message queue service. Can't figure it out as the document is not clear.